# how can i specify the migrations directory for typeorm CLI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

After the new typeorm release a have some troubles to work with migrations.

Some time ago i was using that code and it work

```
entities: ['./src/modules/**/infra/typeorm/entities/*.ts'],
migrations: ['./src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations/*.ts'],
cli: {
  migrationsDir: './src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations'
}
```

But now i cant specify the cli property. To create a new migrations i have to specify the entire migration path

```
npm run typeorm migration:create ./src/database/migrations -n SomeTest
```

is there another way to do that without specify the entire path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Jun 2022, the docs is outdated `-n MigrationName` is no longer supported. You can do this instead:

typescript esm:
`npx typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:create src/database/migration/MigrationFileName` where `MigrationFileName` is the filename you want to create and `src/database/migration/` is the path.

typescript commonjs:
`npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create`

P.S This might be late but this could save others.
P.S I just discover this myself. If this doesn't work in the future, let me know, so I would know as well.

Answer (score 20):

Create ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
  migrations: ['dist/**/migrations/*.js'],
  migrationsTableName: 'history',
});
```

Install "cross-var" package
Add commands in your package.json file

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ormconfig.ts",
"migration:create": "cross-var ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
"migration:generate": "cross-var npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
"migration:run": "npm run build && npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
```

Example command

```
"npm run migration:create --name=Test1"
```

Look this [project](https://github.com/sramocki/nestjs-typeorm-example-migrations)

Answer (score 6):

I have the following scripts in my package.json to solve this problem.

```json
"migration:run": "typeorm -d src/datasource/datasource.ts migration:run",
"migration:create":"cd ./src/db/migrations && typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create",
```

So whenever I want to create a new migration file, I could simply run
`npm run migration:create nameOfMigration` without specifying the entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

In typeorm version 0.3.12 you should use like this in windows.

```
"scripts": {
  "migrate:create": "typeorm migration:create ./src/schemas/typeorm/migration/%NAME%"
},
```

path example: `./src/schemas/typeorm/migration/%NAME%`

command in terminal:

```
NAME=test2 typeorm migration:create
```

Answer (score 0):

As of submitting this answer, there seems not to be a way around it.
You can specify the path when creating new migration just as you have done

> typeorm migration:create -n UserMigration -d src/migrations

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `$npm_config` feature is not supported by yarn. Thus, I've tried the following scripts below as a workaround and it worked for me.

[*Yarn does not support setting npm_config env via CLI parameter like NPM*](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4581)

```
"migration:create":"cd src/migrations && npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create",
"migration:generate":"cd src/migrations && npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate -d <YOUR_DATASOURCE_CONFIG_PATH>",
```

Answer (score 0):

lets make a simple node script to wrap **typeorm migratation:create** command.

target example: **npm run migrate:create create_users_table**

// package.json

```
  {"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx tsc && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
    "migrate": "typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/database/connection.ts",
    "migrate:create": "ts-node ./src/scripts/createMigration.ts",
    "migrate:rollback": "typeorm migration:revert -- -d ./src/database/connection.ts"
  }},
```

./src/scripts/createMigration.ts

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const execAsync = promisify(exec);

const defaultMigrationPath = './src/database/migrations';
const dataSourcePath = './src/database/connection.ts';

async function createMigration(migrationName: string): Promise<void> {
  const migrationFullPath = `${defaultMigrationPath}/${migrationName}`;
  
  try {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await execAsync(
      `npm run typeorm migration:create ${migrationFullPath} -- -d ${dataSourcePath}`
    );

    console.log(stdout);
    if (stderr) {
      console.error('Error:', stderr);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to create migration:', error);
  }
}

const migrationName = process.argv[2];
console.log('name', migrationName);

if (!migrationName) {
  console.error('Please provide a name for the migration.');
  process.exit(1);
}

createMigration(migrationName);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and I solved it by removing the -n to give the name:
**yarn typeorm migration:create** 
but it saves the file in the root folder, even specified in the config.json file, to save it in place you have to pass the
**yarn path typeorm migration:create src/database/migrations/**